# could not uninstall macports completely

Tags: macos, uninstallation, macports, osx-elcapitan, pkg-file

**i used the command sudo port uninstall to uninstall macports but still when i type the command pkgutil --pkgs it shows**

```
com.apple.pkg.BaseSystemResources

com.apple.pkg.ChineseWordlistUpdate.14U1103

com.apple.pkg.ChineseWordlistUpdate.14U1116

com.apple.pkg.ChineseWordlistUpdate.14U1118

com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables

com.apple.pkg.CoreADI

com.apple.pkg.CoreFP

com.apple.pkg.CoreLSKDConfigData.8

com.apple.pkg.CoreSuggestionsConfigData.14U2067

com.apple.pkg.CoreSuggestionsConfigData.14U2082

com.apple.pkg.CoreSuggestionsConfigData.14U2099

com.apple.pkg.DevSDK

com.apple.pkg.DevSDK_OSX1011

com.apple.pkg.Essentials

com.apple.pkg.GatekeeperConfigData.14U2085

com.apple.pkg.GatekeeperConfigData.14U2114

com.apple.pkg.IncompatibleKextConfigData.14U2075

com.apple.pkg.IncompatibleKextConfigData.14U2087

com.apple.pkg.IncompatibleKextConfigData.14U2104

com.apple.pkg.iTunesAccess

com.apple.pkg.iTunesX.12.3.1.delta

com.apple.pkg.iTunesXPatch

com.apple.pkg.MobileDevice

com.apple.pkg.MobileDeviceDevelopment

com.apple.pkg.MRT.14U2061

com.apple.pkg.MRT.14U2081

com.apple.pkg.MRT.14U2111

com.apple.pkg.OSX1011IncompatibleAppList

com.apple.pkg.OSXSDK10.11

com.apple.pkg.RAWCameraUpdate6

com.apple.pkg.RecoveryHDUpdate.15C50

com.apple.pkg.SystemIntegrityProtectionConfig.14U2076

com.apple.pkg.update.os.Combo10.11.2Auto.15C50

com.apple.pkg.X11redirect

com.apple.pkg.XProtectPlistConfigData.14U4030

com.apple.pkg.XProtectPlistConfigData.14U4033

com.apple.update.firmwareupdate

com.adobe.acrobat.AcroRdrDCUpd1500820082_MUI

com.adobe.acrobat.AcroRdrDCUpd1500920069_MUI

com.adobe.acrobat.AcroRdrDCUpd1500920077_MUI

com.adobe.acrobat.DC.reader.app.pkg.MUI

com.adobe.acrobat.DC.reader.appsupport.pkg.MUI

com.adobe.acrobat.DC.reader.browser.pkg.MUI

com.adobe.armdc.app.pkg

com.adobe.pkg.FlashPlayer

com.adobe.RdrServicesUpdater

com.apple.pkg.BootCampESD

com.apple.pkg.ChineseWordlistUpdate.14U1016

com.apple.pkg.ChineseWordlistUpdate.14U1022

com.apple.pkg.ChineseWordlistUpdate.14U1029

com.apple.pkg.ChineseWordlistUpdate.14U1032

com.apple.pkg.ChineseWordlistUpdate.14U1048

com.apple.pkg.ChineseWordlistUpdate.14U1056

com.apple.pkg.ChineseWordlistUpdate.14U1061

com.apple.pkg.ChineseWordlistUpdate.14U1067

com.apple.pkg.ChineseWordlistUpdate.14U1072

com.apple.pkg.ChineseWordlistUpdate.14U1084

com.apple.pkg.CoreADI

com.apple.pkg.CoreFP

com.apple.pkg.CoreLSKDConfigData.8

com.apple.pkg.GarageBand_AppStore

com.apple.pkg.GatekeeperConfigData.14U2010

com.apple.pkg.GatekeeperConfigData.14U2024

com.apple.pkg.GatekeeperConfigData.14U2027

com.apple.pkg.GatekeeperConfigData.14U2030

com.apple.pkg.GatekeeperConfigData.14U2032

com.apple.pkg.GatekeeperConfigData.14U2039

com.apple.pkg.GatekeeperConfigData.14U2050

com.apple.pkg.GatekeeperConfigData.14U2054

com.apple.pkg.GatekeeperConfigData.14U2064

com.apple.pkg.GatekeeperConfigData.14U2066

com.apple.pkg.iMovie_AppStore

com.apple.pkg.IncompatibleKextConfigData.12U2199

com.apple.pkg.InstallMacOSX

com.apple.pkg.iTunesAccess

com.apple.pkg.iTunesX

com.apple.pkg.iTunesXPatch

com.apple.pkg.Keynote6

com.apple.pkg.MobileDevice

com.apple.pkg.Numbers3

com.apple.pkg.Pages5

com.apple.pkg.RAWCameraUpdate6

com.apple.pkg.RecoveryHDUpdate.14D131

com.apple.pkg.RemoteDesktopClient

com.apple.pkg.Safari8.0.6Yosemite

com.apple.pkg.Safari9.0Yosemite

com.apple.pkg.SpeechRecognitionCoreLanguage_en_US

com.apple.pkg.SpeechVoice_en_US_AlexPremium

com.apple.pkg.Xcode

com.apple.pkg.XProtectPlistConfigData.12U4045

com.apple.pkg.XProtectPlistConfigData.12U4046

com.apple.pkg.XProtectPlistConfigData.14U4025

com.apple.pkg.XProtectPlistConfigData.14U4026

com.apple.pkg.XProtectPlistConfigData.14U4027

com.apple.pkg.XProtectPlistConfigData.14U4028

com.apple.pkg.XProtectPlistConfigData.14U4029

com.apple.pkg.XProtectPlistConfigData.14U4030

com.apple.update.firmwareupdate

com.barebones.textwrangler

com.evernote.Evernote

com.microsoft.onenote.mac

com.oracle.jdk7u79

com.oracle.jre

com.swipesapp.Swipes

com.vagrant.vagrant
```

edu.mit.pkg.AppInventorSetupInstaller

GitOSX.Installer.git253Universal.etc.pkg

GitOSX.Installer.git253Universal.git.pkg

```
org.macports.arpack

org.macports.atlas

org.macports.autoconf

org.macports.automake

org.macports.bzip2

org.macports.cairo

org.macports.cctools-headers

org.macports.cctools

org.macports.cloog

org.macports.curl-ca-bundle

org.macports.curl

org.macports.db46

org.macports.db_select

org.macports.dbus

org.macports.epstool

org.macports.expat

org.macports.fftw-3-single

org.macports.fftw-3

org.macports.fontconfig

org.macports.freetype

org.macports.gawk

org.macports.gcc47

org.macports.gcc_select

org.macports.gd2

org.macports.gdbm

org.macports.gettext

org.macports.ghostscript

org.macports.glib2

org.macports.glpk

org.macports.gmp

org.macports.gnuplot

org.macports.gobject-introspection

org.macports.GraphicsMagick

org.macports.graphite2

org.macports.grep

org.macports.gsed

org.macports.harfbuzz

org.macports.hdf5-18

org.macports.isl

org.macports.jasper

org.macports.jbig2dec

org.macports.jpeg

org.macports.lcms

org.macports.lcms2

org.macports.ld64

org.macports.less

org.macports.libedit

org.macports.libffi

org.macports.libgcc

org.macports.libiconv

org.macports.libidn

org.macports.libmng

org.macports.libmpc

org.macports.libpaper

org.macports.libpixman

org.macports.libpng

org.macports.libtool

org.macports.libvpx

org.macports.libxml2

org.macports.llvm-3.3

org.macports.llvm_select

org.macports.lua

org.macports.m4

org.macports.MacPorts

org.macports.mpfr

org.macports.ncurses

org.macports.octave-next

org.macports.openssl

org.macports.pango

org.macports.pcre

org.macports.perl5.12

org.macports.perl5

org.macports.plotutils

org.macports.ppl

org.macports.pstoedit

org.macports.python27

org.macports.python_select

org.macports.qhull

org.macports.qrupdate

org.macports.qscintilla

org.macports.qt4-mac

org.macports.readline

org.macports.sqlite3

org.macports.SuiteSparse

org.macports.texinfo

org.macports.tiff

org.macports.xz

org.macports.zlib

org.octave.cli-app

org.octave.gui-app

org.python.Python.PythonApplications-3.4

org.python.Python.PythonDocumentation-3.4

org.python.Python.PythonFramework-3.4

org.python.Python.PythonUnixTools-3.4

org.r-project.R.mavericks.fw.pkg

org.r-project.R.mavericks.GUI.pkg

org.r-project.x86_64.tcltk.x11

org.r-project.x86_64.texinfo

org.virtualbox.pkg.vboxkexts

org.virtualbox.pkg.virtualbox

org.virtualbox.pkg.virtualboxcli

com.apple.pkg.GarageBand_AppStore

com.apple.pkg.iMovie_AppStore

com.apple.pkg.iPhoto_AppStore

com.apple.pkg.Keynote6

com.apple.pkg.MAContent10_GarageBandCoreContent

com.apple.pkg.MAContent10_PremiumPreLoopsChillwave

com.apple.pkg.MAContent10_PremiumPreLoopsDeepHouse

com.apple.pkg.MAContent10_PremiumPreLoopsDubstep

com.apple.pkg.MAContent10_PremiumPreLoopsElectroHouse

com.apple.pkg.MAContent10_PremiumPreLoopsGarageBand

com.apple.pkg.MAContent10_PremiumPreLoopsHipHop

com.apple.pkg.MAContent10_PremiumPreLoopsJamPack1

com.apple.pkg.MAContent10_PremiumPreLoopsModernRnB

com.apple.pkg.MAContent10_PremiumPreLoopsRemixTools

com.apple.pkg.MAContent10_PremiumPreLoopsRhythmSection

com.apple.pkg.MAContent10_PremiumPreLoopsSymphony

com.apple.pkg.MAContent10_PremiumPreLoopsTechHouse

com.apple.pkg.MAContent10_PremiumPreLoopsWorld

com.apple.pkg.Numbers3

com.apple.pkg.Pages5
```

Answer (score 0):

Those `org.macports.*` packages in pkgutil come from a third-party application installer that was built using MacPorts and bundled the libraries and tools you see listed there, not from MacPorts itself. MacPorts does not register anything with pkgutil (except maybe its own installer package).

Look through the list of components and see if you recognize anything that you downloaded and installed from a website. cloog might be a candidate, for example, but it's hard to be sure since you cut off the list.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!!
I've updated the list please check once again.
Also could you tell me how can I remove these.

Comment: Could be epstool, Octave, or R. Hard to tell from the output, but you may remember installing one of them manually?

Comment: yeah I installed R and octave both recently!